# Angularjs/Java - Get image from rest service method

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, inputstream

My java web application has a rest service method and return a inputstream image.

```
@GET
@Path("/image/{id}")
@Produces("image/png")
public Response buscarFoto(@PathParam("id") Long id,
                           @Context HttpHeaders header,
                           @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    bytes = yakifreeService.getImageStream(id);
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);        


response.setContentType("images/png");
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + "image.png" + "\"");

try {
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    IOUtils.copy(in, out);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(ex.getMessage()).type(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).build();
}

return Response.ok().build();
```

}

The Angularjs client gets the inputstream image as following

```
Image.getImage({ id: $scope.model.image.id }).$promise.then(function (result){
        if (result) {
            $scope.model.image.dataURL = 'data:image/png;base64,' + result;
        }    
    });


function(yakifree) {
    return yakifree.factory("Image", ["$resource", "$rootScope",
        function($resource, $rootScope) {
             var Image = $resource($rootScope.contextApp + '/rest/image/:id', { }, {
                 getImage: { method:'GET', params: {}, isArray: false }

             });

             return Image;
        }]);
});
```

And HTML shows

```
<img data-ng-src="{{model.image.dataURL}}" width="120" height="120">
```

The problem is the HTML does not show image. The result variable in javasript has the value:

```
Resource {0: "�", 1: "P", 2: "N", 3: "G", 4: "
", 5: "↵", 6: "", 7: "↵", 8: "
```

Can someone help me ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the next approach works correctly

```
    $resource(endpoint + 'images/:id', null, {
                getImage: {
                  method: 'GET',
                  responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                  transformResponse: function(data) { return { data : data }}
                }
              })
...
    const response = await resource.getImage({id}).$promise;
    const binary = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(response.data)));
    const img = 'data:image/png;base64,'+ binary;

...

<img src={img}/>
```